# Dynamic routes doesn't work in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with dynamic routes.

I just tried add likes value in posts table to some post.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('post/{$id}/like', 'PostController@like')->name('post.like');
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

And i define 1 custom method in resource controller PostControleler.

**PostController@like**

```
public function like($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->likes++;
    $post->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

and link in blade php view

```
<a href="{{route('post.like', $post)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</a>
```

When clicking on a link, nothing happen, just displayed 404

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

Why that dynamic route doesn't work.

P.S.

That code works if i replace method to **show** instead **like** (it means that the custom method is hindered by something, the code itself is working)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this <a href="{{route('post.like', ['id' => $post])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</a>

Comment: Yes, i already use it previously and nothing, still 404. That means method is successful define but value is not incereased and view not displayed, just 404

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace your href by this below and make shure if $post it's $post of id value or replace it with `$post->id`

```
<a href="{!! route('post.like', [$post]) !!}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</a>
```

and change  get by post (here your are send data to the server that means you will post $id)

```
Route::post('/post/{$id}/like', 'PostController@like')->name('post.like');
```

Comment: Should be work for any method. I put all code in like method to default method show from resource controller 'PostController' and that works! What prevents the work of the custom method?

Comment: no, here you will send $id to like a method to update likes column value, for that, u should use post method.  and change the route of web.php like this :  `Route::resource('post', 'PostController');   Route::get('post/{$id}/like', 'PostController@like')->name('post.like');`

Comment: Yes, but with post method also doesn't work. Tryied with ::any method, same...i think something prevent use custom method (with resourse method, that code works and like value increasing (also with get method) )

Comment: Resource controller blocked custom route, we should define resource controller in web.php after our custom routes.https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: i think u need to add / before post in the name of ur route like this : `Route::post('/post/{$id}/like', 'PostController@like')->name('post.like');`

Answer (score 0):

Damn....i just forgot delete $ sign in custom route.

Should be:

```
Route::get('post/{post}/like', 'PostController@like')->name('post.like');
```